# Database error message

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Got this SQLite error message when trying to save information to the database. I'm still pretty new to SQL so would appreciate help to figuring out whats happening here.[1st part of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6K41.png) and [2nd part of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bolrG.png)

Comment: It would help if you 1) Provided code that the error pointed to and 2) Copied the error into your question instead of images.

Answer (score 0):

the colum wishdb does not exist in your table, it's written in the first line of your error.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty obvious. It says you don't have a wishdb column.

If you added it to the table schema, the problem should be, that you just deployed the new APK to your device. If you do so, the app doesn't recreate the DB with the new schema.

Try uninstalling your app and than deploy the new APK.